Movie with a girl watching a magical horse or unicorn
When I was younger I remember watching a movie about a unicorn/horse (can't remember which one) but all I remember about it is a girl looks out her window and sees a horse and then I think the horse disappears and at the end of the film the horse turns out to be magical or something and loads of horses run on a wave onto the shore to see the girl

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you watch this?  Is the setting contemporary or fantasy/mediaeval?

Live Action or animated?

When you were younger - so, like, 1950 or so?

It's been a while since I saw it (although it's repeated every year at Christmas Eve on German television), so I put forward:
The Last Unicorn (1982, adapted from a book from 1968)
Details as I remember them:

It's an animated movie with music and singing, Disney-style, but darker story-wise. Drawing style is somewhat realistic (except for thinness) for characters that are supposed to be beautiful vs. cartoonish (small, plump, huge nose, hair standing off in all directions) for ugly characters.
There is a girl—actually, she's a unicorn, but in the progression of the movie, she first disguises herself as a horse and is then turned into a girl. This may explain the OP's confusion about unicorn vs. horse.
On her search for the other unicorns, she ends up being held in a castle/tower, with a dream sequence of herself as a unicorn again. She's slowly forgetting who she is. I think the dream sequence ends with her standing at the window and her remember-myself-as-unicorn-persona vanishing into the distance.
Despite the title, there are other unicorns; they have fled from the BBEG (big bad evil guy) into the sea and are calling to her. When the BBEG is defeated, the other unicorns emerge from their hiding in the sea. The foam on top of waves forms into loads and loads of unicorns.

Missing from OP's description but worth mentioning:

BBEG is actually not a single guy but a duo:

A skinny old geezer controlling
A flaming bull.


A memorable scene involves an undead talking skeleton that asks for wine but is happy to get an empty bottle because it can remember the taste.
The unicorn/girl is accompanied by:

An untalented wizard. The only spells that he can control are illusions, like putting a horn on the disguised-as-a-horse unicorn for even more horse vs. unicorn confusion, duh. He's the one who turns the unicorn into a girl by basically telling magic to just do its thing. He's mighty proud of that, although he didn't have any control and can't turn her back.
⇨ Discount fantasy wizard
A female robber. After first attacking the others, she joins them in search of a better life. She is also a candidate for being seen as a girl because she isn't actually old, just not pretty.
⇨ Discount fantasy thief
The son of the BBEG-geezer. He falls in love with the girl (unicorn) and saves/fights for her until she remembers that she's actually a unicorn, turns herself back, and rescues him.
⇨ Discount fantasy knight




Is this The Secret of Moonacre (2008)...?
It's loosely based on the 1946 children's novel, The Little White Horse by Elizabeth Goudge.

Maria inherits a book of secrets from her dad. She moves to her uncle's Moonacre estate. A family curse was cast on the valley. Only Maria can break it using her book.

The story is set in Victorian England.
The protagonist, Maria Merryweather, is a 13-year-old girl who moves from London to her uncle's estate in Moonacre Valley in the West Country after her father's death (her mother passed away some time earlier).
About half an hour into the film, Maria looks out of her bedroom window at night and sees a glowing white horse appear and disappear in the garden, as if it were a ghost. She subsequently glimpses this horse a few more time in other locations.
Around an hour and a half into the film, she leaps off a cliff into the sea, seemingly to her death. Then a large wave appears on the horizon, rapidly approaching the shore, and from the wave emerges a herd of white horses, led by a white unicorn with Maria on its back, galloping along the surface of the water. The unicorn returns Maria safely to the shore while the other horses  disappear back into the sea.







In case you're thinking of an animated movie, your description made me think of The Fantastic Adventures of Unico. I recall a scene similar to what you've described in one of the three movies they made, maybe the second (Unico In the Island of Magic)?

